# Post array using formData

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add images, few string information and array using formData. I can successfully add images, string but can't add array information while adding. It always passes array as a string.Any help would be appreciated. My code

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('departure_city',departure_city);
form_data.append('inclusion_icons', inc_icons);
form_data.append('theme_icons',theme_icons);

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  data: form_data,
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log("Success");
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function (data) {
  console.log("Error");
  console.log(data);
});
```

`inclusion_icons` and `theme_icons` are arrayz, however I'm getting them as a string.

Comment: All form data is sent as a string. It's down to you to deserialize it to the correct types in your server side code. Also, remove `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice to use

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan . I'll check what I can do in server side.